# Confusing details in Support vector machine's papers using Sequential Minimal Optimization

Tags: c++, machine-learning, svm

Recently I have been trying to learn about Suppor vector machine using Sequential Minimal Optimization by Platt (1998). Here is their original paper:

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=68391

And here is another link:

http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/smo-svm.pdf

The second link describes the implementation details of the original paper, including a C++ source code which can be downloaded from here: 
 ftp://www.ai.mit.edu/pub/users/tlp/projects/svm/svm-smo/

(The code wouldn't run, however, due to some problems with a drand_48() function available only on Linux, but I have the source code of that function already and it wouldn't take long for the code to run)

However there are some strange and confusing details in their implementation:
1) In the first link, page 10, procedure takeStep (i1,i2), there is a line:

```
  if |a2 - alpha2 | < eps* (a2 + alpha2 + eps) 
             return 0;
```

where a2 is the "new" Lagrange multiplier and alpha2 is the "old" one. I don't really understand what this line does. All I know is that, within this function: First it tries to find the 2 Lagrange Multipliers that minimizes (or maximizes, as in the 2nd link) the objective function, with some condtitions (namely y1 * alpha1 + y2 * alph2 = const) then it must be checked against the KKT conditions ( the 2 alphas has to be in a box (0,C)(0,C) ). It does so by finding the point where the 1st derivative vanishes, then it checks the second derivative at that point to see if it really is a minimum, if it isn't, check the objective function at the bounds (L and H in the papers). SMO will move the Lagrange multipliers to the end point that has the lowest value of the
objective function.

Here is an excerpt from the first paper:

"If the objective function is the same at both ends (within a small ε for roundoff error) and the kernel obeys Mercer’s conditions, then the joint minimization cannot make progress." (page8)

I think this is what describes the meaning of the line, but I just can't understand how it works!

2) The (19) :6 complicated formulas at page 8, first paper: I don't really understand what they mean.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

12.3 Psuedo code reads

```
if (|a2 - alph2| < eps*(a2+alpa2+eps))
    return 0;
```

`eps` is ε, *epsilon*, the small roundoff error. So if the absolute (positive) difference becomes too small, then the next line would produce a tiny value

```
a1 = alph1+s*(alph2-a2)
```

so the function terminates because the function cannot progress with such small increments.

Comment: But why not just |a2 - alph2| < eps ?? Why not make it simple? When I substitute the first inequation into the second one, I get:: s*(alpha2-a2)< s* eps* (a2 + alpha2 + eps) . But it doesn't make any sense! :(